# Am I using RSA encryption and signing correctly?

Tags: encryption, .net, rsa

I like to make sure I got the encrypting part right in my app. I plan to open source this code. You can get the two related files at: https://gist.github.com/lameguy7quick/1e998aad673354d2661b.

Have I made any mistakes? I know I didn't understand HMAC at the time of writing.

The idea is simple. I load the recipient public key. Encrypt a randomly made AES key. Encode the message with said AES then stuff it into a tcp connection. It seems to work correctly have I overlooked anything? I have a feeling maybe the aes should have a randomly made IV but the key itself is randomly generated so maybe I don't need to?

I also use SHA1CryptoServiceProvider I think I should use SHA512CryptoServiceProvider.

Did I sign correctly? It says it is signed but I'm not sure if there is an attack on it

```
public byte[] SendMessage(byte[] recipient_pubkey, byte[] replyTo, string txt, byte[] prvkey, byte[] pubkey)
{
    RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    var msgid = new byte[16];
    rng.GetBytes(msgid);
    using (var aes = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        byte[] rsa_aes_key;
        RSAParameters recipient_rsap;
        Shared.LoadKey2(Shared.pubToPem(recipient_pubkey), null, out recipient_rsap);
        using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            rsa.ImportParameters(recipient_rsap);
            rsa_aes_key = rsa.Encrypt(aes.Key, false);
        }
        var aesmsg = EncodeMessage(recipient_pubkey, msgid, replyTo, txt, prvkey, pubkey, aes.Key, Shared.FixedIV_16bytes);
        if (rsa_aes_key.Length + aesmsg.Length > 1024 * 15) throw new Exception();
        sw.WriteByte((byte)ClientServerCmd.SendMessage);
        sw.WriteShort((short)recipient_pubkey.Length);
        sw.Write(recipient_pubkey, 0, recipient_pubkey.Length);
        sw.WriteShort(rsa_aes_key.Length + aesmsg.Length);
        sw.Write(rsa_aes_key, 0, rsa_aes_key.Length);
        sw.Write(aesmsg, 0, aesmsg.Length);
        sw.Flush();
        var resp = sr.ReadByte();
        if (resp != (byte)ClientServerCmd.KeyLenOk)
            throw new Exception();
        resp = sr.ReadByte();
        if (resp == (byte)ClientServerCmd.NotRegistered)
            throw new MyException("User you're writing to does not exist");
        if (resp != (byte)ClientServerCmd.Success)
            throw new Exception();
    }
    return msgid;
}

byte[] EncodeMessage(byte[] recipient_pubkey, byte[]msgid, byte[] replyTo, string txt, byte[] prvkey, byte[] pubkey, byte[] aes_key, byte[] aes_iv)
{
    if (replyTo == null)
    {
        replyTo = new byte[16];
    }
    var txtbuf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txt);
    var SignMessage = prvkey != null;
    byte[] hash = null;
    if (SignMessage)
    {
        using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            RSAParameters rsap;
            Shared.LoadKey2(Shared.prvToPem(prvkey), null, out rsap);
            rsa.ImportParameters(rsap);
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) //sign
            {
                ms.Write(msgid, 0, msgid.Length);
                ms.Write(replyTo, 0, replyTo.Length);
                ms.WriteShort((short)txtbuf.Length);
                ms.Write(txtbuf, 0, txtbuf.Length);
                ms.WriteShort((short)pubkey.Length);
                ms.Write(pubkey, 0, pubkey.Length);
                ms.WriteShort((short)recipient_pubkey.Length);
                ms.Write(recipient_pubkey, 0, recipient_pubkey.Length);
                ms.Position = 0;
                hash = rsa.SignData(ms, new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider());
            }
        }
    }
    byte[] c1;
    using (var ms1 = new MemoryStream())
    using (var ms = new BZip2OutputStream(ms1))
    {
        ms.Write(txtbuf, 0, txtbuf.Length);
        ms.Close();
        c1 = ms1.ToArray();
    }
    var compressText = c1.Length < txtbuf.Length;
    byte[] aesmsg;
    byte[] aeskey;
    using (var aes = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        aeskey = aes.Key;
        aes.IV = Shared.FixedIV_16bytes;
        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes_key, aes_iv))
            using (CryptoStream sw2 = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                sw2.WriteByte((Byte)((compressText ? 1 : 0) | (SignMessage ? 2 : 0)));
                sw2.Write(msgid, 0, msgid.Length);
                sw2.Write(replyTo, 0, replyTo.Length);
                if (compressText)
                {
                    sw2.WriteShort((short)c1.Length);
                    sw2.Write(c1, 0, c1.Length);
                }
                else
                {
                    sw2.WriteShort((short)txtbuf.Length);
                    sw2.Write(txtbuf, 0, txtbuf.Length);
                }
                if (SignMessage)
                {
                    sw2.WriteShort((short)pubkey.Length);
                    sw2.Write(pubkey, 0, pubkey.Length);
                    sw2.WriteShort((short)hash.Length);
                    sw2.Write(hash, 0, hash.Length);
                }
            }
            msEncrypt.Flush();
            aesmsg = msEncrypt.ToArray();
        }
    }
    return aesmsg;
}
```

Comment: Should have been migrated to code review instead.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just use TLS?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed IV is a certainly not right.

IV for AES CBC should not be predictable. Typically you make it random and include it with the ciphertext.

A mac is important to avoid chosen ciphertext attacks, you are reading and writing your own format you have to worry about manipulation of your ciphertext allowing something to be exposed, your aes code likely will throw a padding exception that could be used to recover the plaintext by sending modified ciphertext to your receiver.

It's good that your code will be open source, opening it up to analysis and patches, but you should be aware the [applying cryptography correctly is difficult](http://sockpuppet.org/blog/2013/07/22/applied-practical-cryptography/) and easy to make mistakes.

If you can adapt a high level library, like [Keyczar](https://github.com/jbtule/keyczar-dotnet/wiki/Session-Encryption) (I ported it to c#), you'll be in better shape, though nothing's perfect.

Comment: Are you sure I need a unique IV if the AES key is randomize for each *message*? I don't understand the wiki's HMAC code well but would this work? (Bad pseudo code) `var hmac = SHA512CryptoServiceProvider; hmac.write(rsa_aes_key); hmac.write(aesmsg); var hmac2=...; hmac2.write(hmac); hmac2.write(rsa_aes_key); return hmac2`. What I think i'm doing is hashing the rsa key and aes message to get a sha hash. Then I hash that result and the rsa key for my final hash result. This sounds correct to me

Comment: I didn't find anything when i searched pss. I believe .net does include padding so i don't believe i need to implement OAEP? The hmac idea I had followed http://www.thoughtcrime.org/blog/the-cryptographic-doom-principle/ correctly (I did #3).